# what are the Best way to replace US Word to UK Word from XML file

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xml-parsing

The texts for each of my pages are defined in external language files. For example in somthing.xml.

How can I auto change the spelling in somthing.xml from US English to UK English?.

In somthing.xml, I know I can use str_replace for each text I want to show, but that will be very time consuming to implement.

So, I need best way to replace US Word to UK Word from XML file. And any dictionary API are there for solving this one..??

My xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?><pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
<pkg:part pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:padding="512">
<pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
<pkg:part pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" pkg:name="/word/document.xml">
<pkg:xmlData>
<w:document xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
<w:body>
<w:p w:rsidP="003E0D43" w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="CL"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t>[GQ: PLEASE CONFIRM THAT ALL AUTHOR INFORMATION, INCLUDING NAMES, AFFILIATIONS, SEQUENCE, AND CONTACT DETAILS, IS CORRECT.]</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidP="003E0D43" w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="CL"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t>[GQ: PLEASE REVIEW THE ENTIRE DOCUMENT FOR TYPOGRAPHICAL ERRORS, MATHEMATICAL ERRORS, AND ANY OTHER NECESSARY CORRECTIONS; CHECK HEADINGS, TABLES, AND FIGURES.]</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidP="003E0D43" w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="CL"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t>[GQ: PLEASE CONFIRM YOU HAVE REVIEWED THIS PROOF TO YOUR SATISFACTION AND UNDERSTAND THIS IS YOUR FINAL OPPORTUNITY FOR REVIEW PRIOR TO PUBLICATION.]</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidP="003E0D43" w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="CL"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t>[GQ: PLEASE CONFIRM THAT THE FUNDING AND CONFLICT OF INTEREST STATEMENTS ARE ACCURATE.]</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidP="003E0D43" w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="AF"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:rPrChange w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T11:25:00Z" w:id="6">
<w:rPr/>
</w:rPrChange>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="7" w:name="aff1"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:rPr>
<w:vertAlign w:val="superscript"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>1</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="7"/>
<w:del w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T10:32:00Z" w:id="8">
<w:r w:rsidDel="00EC58EA" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:delText xml:space="preserve">International CyberCrime Research Centre, School of Criminology, </w:delText>
</w:r>
</w:del>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t xml:space="preserve">Simon Fraser University, Burnaby, </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:del w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T10:32:00Z" w:id="9">
<w:r w:rsidDel="00EC58EA" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:delText>BC</w:delText>
</w:r>
</w:del>
<w:ins w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T10:32:00Z" w:id="10">
<w:r w:rsidR="00EC58EA" w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:t>British Columbia</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:ins>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:rPr>
<w:rPrChange w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T11:25:00Z" w:id="11">
<w:rPr/>
</w:rPrChange>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>, Canada</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00074820" w:rsidRPr="009C081D" w:rsidRDefault="00074820" w:rsidP="003E0D43">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="TEXT"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:rPrChange w:id="401" w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T11:25:00Z">
<w:rPr/>
</w:rPrChange>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:rPr>
<w:rPrChange w:id="402" w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T11:25:00Z">
<w:rPr/>
</w:rPrChange>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>The online media output of extremist organizations has allowed their messages to be seen and heard by vast audiences, however, propaganda is even more effective when it inspires or pushes the individuals exposed to it towards radicalization or recruitment. Online media has become an increasingly important avenue for recruitment and has greatly enhanced the ability of extremist organizations to deliver their radicalizing messages (
</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:rPr>
<w:rPrChange w:id="403" w:author="Copyeditor43" w:date="2017-03-03T11:25:00Z">
<w:rPr/>
</w:rPrChange>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="009C081D">
<w:rPr>
</w:p>
</w:body>
```

My US & UK word List like below,

```
 us_words_list = array('colors','flavors','organizations','radicalizing');
 uk_words_list = array('colours', 'flavours','organisations','radicalising');
```

Am using java code, So anyone know about this. Please let me know.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks.

Comment: can you  provide some US word that is present in the sample xml

Comment: can you check if this proves useful to you:https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate

Comment: @Rajeev Akotkar, thanks for your effort. And present 
 US Word like organizations,radicalizing.. Still I didn't check your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DOM Parser. Parsing XML File and Reading 'w:t' (Node) tags. Then using Node.getTextContent() and Node.setTextContent(usWord.replaceAll(word, ukWord)).

Answer (score 1):

This might prove useful to you :

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate